# syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ']'

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, checkbox

Estoy haciendo un formulario de registro y en ese formulario hay 2 checkboxes de género o sexo y para validar uso el método post pero al validar los checkboxes uso un if pero me da error para ver si alguien me ayuda a corregir lo que tengo mal, aquí les muestro el código.

```
public function register()
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $datosRegistro = [
            'privilegio' => '2',
            'email' => trim($_POST['email']),
            'nombres' => trim($_POST['nombres']),
            'contrasena' => password_hash(trim($_POST['contrasena']) , PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            if (isset($_POST['sexo'])) {
                'sexo' = $_POST['sexo'];
            }else {
                'sexo' = '';
            }
         ];

         if ($this->usuario->register($datosRegistro)) {
            
         }else{

         }
    }else{
        $this->view('pages/register');
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué hace un `if/else` dentro de una estructura? Obvio marcará error de sintaxis. Puedes hacer el pre-calculo fuera del array y el resultado lo incluyes cuando defines ese array.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo como indica @aeportugal y quitar el `if/else` fuera del array y luego incluir su resultado en el array, o bien podrías hacerlo más o menos así:

```
public function register()
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $datosRegistro = [
            'privilegio' => '2',
            'email' => trim($_POST['email']),
            'nombres' => trim($_POST['nombres']),
            'contrasena' => password_hash(trim($_POST['contrasena']) , PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            'sexo' => $_POST['sexo']?? ''
         ];

         if ($this->usuario->register($datosRegistro)) {
            
         }else{

         }
    }else{
        $this->view('pages/register');
    }
}
```

donde hacemos el **if** camuflado con la sintaxis del [operador de fusión de null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) (??) sin romper la estructura del array.